# No views present in dist when building with grunt

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman, yeoman-generator-angular

I have an angular app that I have scaffolded using `yeoman`.

When I am trying to build with grunt, no views directory is generated in `dist/`

This is how my GruntFile looks

```
htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: false,
          conservativeCollapse: false,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    ngtemplates: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          module: 'tweetSearchApp',
          htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
          usemin: 'scripts/scripts.js'
        },
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        src: 'views/{,*/}*.html',
        dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
      }
    },
```

And this is how my grunt logs look like

```
Running "ngtemplates:dist" (ngtemplates) task
File .tmp/templateCache.js created.
>> Usemin has not created uglify.generated yet!
```

And

```
Running "usemin:html" (usemin) task
Replaced 2 references to assets

Running "usemin:css" (usemin) task
Replaced 2 references to assets

Running "usemin:js" (usemin) task
Replaced 2 references to assets

Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
Minified 2 files
```

But I still cannot see any views folder generated in my `dist/` folder

Please help me with the configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look to this link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates

Grunt is caching your HTML templates with $templateCache. That means all your Html files were included in the script*.js file which was generated in dist/scripts/script*.js.

That is why the views directory is not being generated in dist/

Comment: if my build is not able to install a specific template throwing 404 on it, while it's working fine in the local before build, is there a good way to debug it?

Answer (score -2):

Make change in your gruntfile.js

htmlmin. files.src: ['*.html', '{,*/}*.html']and

copy.dist.files.src:[
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            '{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]

In this way it is working for me.

Comment: Please do explain why this should work & try to format the code